# Using SQL Express server in place of MSSQL - driver differences?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sql-server-express

I just started on a project where all the developers are using a central database while developing. No one was happy with this situation, so I took it upon myself to make a solution where we could all use local databases instead.

The central database uses MS SQL Server, while it seems like the sensible option for a single developer is SQL Express. While I am able to make the application connect to the express server, there are some differences in the way data is returned. Most prominently, `datetime2` objects are returned as structured data objects from MSSQL but as plain strings from Express.

I have confirmed that the relevant columns are `datetime2` fields in the database, and seem to be identical in every way. Looking at the connection strings however, it seems like different drivers are used for the different databases. The central database uses this

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=***;Database=***;UID=***;PWD=***
```

While the Express database uses this string that was displayed by the installation program

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=***;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

I am not familiar enough with MS databases to know what the difference is between `SQL Server` and `SQL Server Native Client 11.0`, and it has been difficult to find information about this. It seems like ODBC might be involved in some way, but I haven't been able to find out which of the drivers are related to OBBC, if any.

If I try to use `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` for the Express database, I get the following error

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'Trusted_Connection'
```

As far as I can tell, `Trusted_Connection` means that it is using the native Windows authentication, and it doesn't seem like I can add users to the Express database. Providing my own username and password instead of `Trusted_Connection` results in a `login failed` message.

Given all this, I would be grateful if someone could help me navigate the intricacies of database servers and drivers available, and figure out the reason for the difference in return values. Thanks!

Comment: If the product environment uses sql server, I'd give the developers the same. Why do you want the developers to work on Express?

Comment: Express, Standard, Enterprise, Developer editions of SQL Server all use the same drivers they just have different functionality available (with Express being the most limited and Enterprise/Developer having the most). But for all the versions you have full control over then users and logins that the instance has. `CREATE LOGIN  [Domain\ADAccount] FROM WINDOWS;` works on all of them.

Comment: "SQL Server" is the ancient (circa SQL Server 2000) ODBC driver that ships with Windows. It will return `datetime2` values as strings. For best results you should be using a newer ODBC driver version like "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server".

Comment: @HoneyBadger I was under the assumption that we would need licenses for that, but I see now that might not be true. I'll check out the option of running the same SQL server on developers machines

Comment: @Larnu is that for creating a domain account? I work in a company with houndreds of employees and don't have access to that, nor would it seem necessary

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you, that's the kind of info I was desperately trying to find. However, `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` doesn't seem to support `Trusted_Connecion` - is there a newer ODBC driver that does that?

Comment: Version 17 is the latest, if I recall, @Vegard, and it certainly supports Trusted Connections.

Comment: *"doesn't seem to support Trusted_Connecion"* - First you have to spell it correctly. ;) Then you have to pass it the value `Yes`, as in `;Trusted_Connection=Yes`

Comment: @GordThompson Well darn, seems like the value changed from `True` to `Yes` somewhere between the `SQL Server` driver and the recent OBDC... I need to debug a bit more but I think this was the solution, if you want to turn that into an answer I'll accept it